# VS 2012 - 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, out-of-memory

I am getting this error when handling archive files.

```
System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
at System.IO.MemoryStream.set_Capacity(Int32 value)
at System.IO.MemoryStream.EnsureCapacity(Int32 value)
at System.IO.MemoryStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
at System.IO.Stream.InternalCopyTo(Stream destination, Int32 bufferSize)
at System.IO.Stream.CopyTo(Stream destination)
at System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive.Init(Stream stream, ZipArchiveMode mode, Boolean leaveOpen)
at System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive..ctor(Stream stream, ZipArchiveMode mode, Boolean leaveOpen, Encoding entryNameEncoding)
```

Here is my code.

```
ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(packageFile); 
var jbossZip = archive.GetEntry(jbossFileName);
```

Please note that my archive file is 170mb in size. Does anyone know a solution for this issue?

Comment: Show your work also..

Comment: How are you "handling"? Show some code

Comment: Read http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/08/out-of-memory-does-not-refer-to-physical-memory.aspx

Comment: Did you use `https://www.nuget.org/packages/DotNetZip/` or something else? show some code

Comment: @JPHellemons He used `System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive`.

Comment: Can you open this zip file using other zip utilities?

Comment: @Mark Yes. I can open it from 7zip and Winrar.

Comment: @wcwchamara Can your program open a smaller zip file?

Comment: @Mark Yes. Even for this archive file also sometimes it is working without any trouble.